# Jquery and Bootstrap popover: load() function duplicates GET request

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<a href="#" title="blabla" data-comm="/test.php" data-poload="/test.php">Load ops</a>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
$('*[data-comm]').bind('hover',function() {
var e=$(this);
$.get(e.data('comm'),function(d) {
    e.popover({content: d}).popover('show');
});
});
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3. when i hover `HMM2` it sends GET request to test.php, HOWEVER when i unhover `HMM2` it sends another, unwanted GET request. Is there any way to force it to send GET request only when i hover over it? i want it to being executed ONLY when the mouse pointer enters the element, not when it leaves him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

> A function to execute when the mouse pointer **enters or leaves** the element.

Use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) simply:

```
$('*[data-comm]').mouseenter(function(event){ ... });
```